# ¿ Como puedo hacer que la salida de este código sea la matriz sin los corchetes y de manera vertical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Como podría hacer que la salida de este código sea la matriz sin los corchetes y además de manera vertical

```
from random import randint

a = int(input("Ingrese su número: "))

matriz = []

def llenar_matriz(a):
    matriz = []
 

for r in range(a):
    fila = []

    for c in range(a):
        fila.append(randint(1, 10))
      

    matriz.append(fila)
        
  
return matriz


resultado = llenar_matriz(a) 
#goal = str(resultado[c][r]) +'\t'
print(resultado)
```

en si lo que espero que imprima en pantalla es algo así:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

esos ceros representarían los números aleatorios.

Comment: simplemente recorre la lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes iterar por los miembros de las listas para conseguir la salida que quieres, por ejemplo:

```
for fila in resultado:
    print("".join(f"{x:3} " for x in fila))
```

El primer for itera por la matriz, obteniendo cada fila, y el segundo va iterando por los elementos de dicha fila, construyendo una cadena con cada número a través de un f-string aplicado a cada elemento.

El resultado es algo como esto:

```
Ingrese su número: 5
  4  10   6   3   9
  6   8   7   3   3
  5   1   3  10  10
 10   5  10   1   3
  1   2  10   4  10
```